# Smyfony 2: Expected argument of type "number", "double" given

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make a form in Symfony 2.8. In my entity class i have a field defined as follows:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="number")
*/
private $someFloatValue;
```

Then in controller i'm constructing a form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($attribute)
->add('someFloatValue', NumberType::class) ...etc.
```

Which renders a beatiful html form.

However if i submit the form with value let's say 2.8 i'm receiving an error:

```
Expected argument of type "number", "double" given
```

What's even more frustrating, submiting integer values into the form results in the same exact error.

Could anyone please explain me why is it happeining?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out. I don't know why i used orm column type 'number' but that was wrong. After changing to **'decimal'**:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="decimal")
*/ 
private $someFloatValue;
```

Everything works as expected.